# exponential of elementary matrix $\exp(tE_{a,b})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, taylor-expansion

> $E_{a,b}$ is the elementary $n\times n$ matrix with $1$ in $(a,b)$-entry and $0$ elsewhere. Compute $\exp(tE_{a,b})$ for $a$ not equal to $b$.

If $a=b$ then they would be on the diagonal, so taking powers of this diagonal matrix is straightforward. So, I could use the Taylor expansion of $\exp(X)$.

But I am not sure for the case: $a$ not equal to $b$.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens when you square the matrix in that case?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $a \neq b$, then compute $\exp[tE_{a,b}]$ using the power series.  Since $E_{a,b}$ is nilpotent, this gives you a polynomial on $t$ with matrix coefficients.